# Quickblox link error _iconv on simulator builds

Tags: ios, iconv, quickblox

Am adding QuickBlox to my iOS app and getting a link error for _iconv, _iconv_open &_iconv_close.

I have added all the libraries/frameworks as per QuickBlox's instructions. The only differences I can see is that in their instructions they use the libraries from the iOS 5.0 folder while mine are all in iOS 7.0, and that I have added libxml2.dylib not libxml.dylib (as libxml2.dylib is in that iOS7 folder).

Curiously this occurs only on iPhone simulator builds - building for a device is fine.

Comment: QuickBlox doesn't iconv library, are you sure that other libs don't use it?

Comment: The error goes away if I remove the QuickBlox framework... "_iconv", referenced from:
      _mem_cd_iconv in Quickblox(striconv.o)
      _str_cd_iconv in Quickblox(striconv.o)

Comment: Simple enough to fix this by including libiconv.dylib - when I first ran into this problem it was part of a much larger issue caused by xcode always looking for the armvx libs instead of 386 ones for the simulator. Not quite sure why it now only needs that library for the simulator build though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple enough to fix this by including libiconv.dylib - when I first ran into this problem it was part of a much larger issue caused by xcode always looking for the armvx libs instead of 386 ones for the simulator. Not quite sure why it now only needs that library for the simulator build though.

Have posted this as the answer for anyone glancing here to see if it was answered.